# How to have observable treeview

Tags: javafx, treeview, tornadofx

I am working on an app which requires TreeView. 
I'm able to generate the Treeview but facing issue with dynamically updating the treeview based on underlying dataset change.

Classes:

```
data class Channels(
    val channel: Channel? = null
)

data class Channel(
     val id: String? = null,
     val name: String? = null,
     val parentChannelId: String? = null
)
```

Data List :

```
var channels = observableListOf(
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "pc1", name = "P Channel 1")),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "c11", name = "Child 1-1", parentChannelId = "pc1")),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "c12", name = "Child 1-2", parentChannelId = "pc1")),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "c121", name = "Child 1-2-1", parentChannelId = "c12")),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "c111", name = "Child 1-1-1", parentChannelId = "c11")),
    Channels(
        channel = Channel(
            id = "c1111",
            name = "Child 1-1-1-1",
            parentChannelId = "c111"
        )
    ),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "pc2", name = "P Channel 2")),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "pc3", name = "P Channel 3")),
    Channels(channel = Channel(id = "c31", name = "Child 3-1", parentChannelId = "pc3"))
)
```

Treeview :

```
treeview<Channels> {                           
    isShowRoot = false                           
    root = TreeItem()
    cellFormat { text = it.channel?.name }
    populate { parent -> 
        if (parent == root) channels.filter { 
            it.channel?.parentChannelId == null 
        } else channels.filter { 
            it.channel?.parentChannelId == parent.value?.channel?.id 
        } 
    }
}
```

Now when I modify the `channels` list, treeview doesn't gets updated.
I've been stuck on this since 3-4 days. 
Please help.

Comment: listen for treeModificationEvent on root

Comment: But since the treeview is not getting updated, how will that event get triggered?

Comment: then there's something wrong with your setup - time for a [mcve] :)

Comment: I think it is already a minimal reproducible example. But I added the classes as well.

Comment: @EdvinSyse Please help